# Moving from Visual Sourcesafe to Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, migration, dvcs, visual-sourcesafe

What's the best way to move a Visual Sourcesafe repository to Mercurial (I'm interested in retaining all history)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While I haven't made that particular conversion, I have gone from VSS to SVN using (IIRC) [this script](http://www.pumacode.org/projects/vss2svn).  You'll probably want to look into tailor and do a search for vss2hg.  Also keep in mind that it may make sense to go through an intermediate step like vss2svn + svn2hg or similar.

The primary bit of advice I'd give though is: script the conversion so you can re-run it easily.  That will let you run nightly conversions from VSS to Hg and make sure that everything is converting correctly before you pull the trigger on it.

Answer (score 13):

I am the author of the vss2hg.pl script and have used it to move many projects from VSS to Mercurial.  It has one or two minor bugs where some comments are not completely converted but I haven't seen any other issues.  It converts complete history and works-around a problem with VSS where a user's PC clock can affect the order in which changes appear to be made.

A version of the script is available [here](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/SourceSafeConversion).

Comment: the website is no longer there looks like

Comment: Use the version linked from @Edmund below; he's maintaining it now as we've kicked the VSS habit.

Answer (score 6):

I used the vss2hg.pl script from [here](http://trojanfoe.googlepages.com/visualsourcesafetomercurialmigrationtool). It is a Perl script, so you need to install [ActivePerl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/) first.

It worked great, but I ran into a problem with the dates. It turns out that the script supports three kinds of date formats. By default it is set to the UK date format (in line 547). The other two date formats are commented out in the code. After enabling the US date format, the script converted my SourceSafe database without a problem.

Comment: I made some fixes to the script. You can download it [here](http://edmundv.home.xs4all.nl/sw/vss2hg.pl).

Comment: It seems most of the published links to vss2hg.pl are broken. Can you provide corrections or redirects as appropriate? I have discovered after some trial and error that an old version of the script (linked to from http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/SourceSafeConversion) is available at http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/SourceSafeConversion?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=vss2hg.pl and a more recent version is available (but not published anywhere except Google search results) from http://edmundv.home.xs4all.nl/sw/vss2hg.pl

Answer (score 5):

The Mercurial wiki has this page, which might be of interest: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/SourceSafeConversion. I've never used Visual source safe, so I don't have any personal experience with it.

I also found a [mail from Patrick Mézard](http://markmail.org/message/2p5s2tg4dqa47r3r) about the subject, but unfortunately he writes that a VSS converter will be difficult. He also talks about converting to Subversion first, and then from Subversion to Mercurial. I guess that means that there are VSS -> SVN converts out there. You can probably google that yourself.

Answer (score 3):

I have done a conversion from SourceSafe to Mercurial for a client. I first converted the SourceSafe database to a Subversion repository and then from Subversion to Mercurial using the hg convert extension. See [my blog post](http://pwigle.wordpress.com/2010/12/03/migrating-from-visual-sourcesafe-to-mercurial/) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried using vss2hg and ran into a problem that it only pickup up and converted 1 user. This means all my changesets etc will not be accurate as I won't be able to see who did them. Is this because I've not pre-setup all the required users in hg?

Comment: You might have better luck asking this as its own question.